# suppose that a fair $n-$sided die is rolled $n$ independent times. A match occurs if side i is observed on the $i^{th}$ trial, $i = 1, 2, . . . , n$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that a fair $n-$sided die is rolled $n$ independent times.
A match occurs if side i is observed on the $i^{th}$ trial, $i = 1, 2, . . . , n$.

1. Show that the probability of at least one match is $1- (
       \frac{n-1}{n})^{n}= 1- (1- \frac{1}{n})^{n}$
2. Find the limit of this probability as n increases without bound.

For (1) what is the thinking process for this one, by induction?

Comment: I don't know that induction is strictly necessary here... the induction step wouldn't be used.  Directly is fine in my opinion.  That said, the problem is *very* similar to the question of "*what is the probability that you rolled at least one $1$ in $n$ rolls of an $n$-sided die*" for which the common strategy is to look instead at the opposite event of "*what is the probability that in $n$ rolls of an $n$-sided die you rolled no $1$'s.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each positive integer $n$, let $X_{1,n},\ldots,X_{n,n}\stackrel{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}\sim\mathrm{Unif}\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_{k,n}$. Then the probability of at least one match in the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ trial is
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(S_n>0) &= 1-\mathbb P(S_n=0)\\
&= 1- \mathbb P\left(\sum_{k=1}^n X_{k,n} = 0 \right)\\
&= 1 -  \left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^n\\
&= 1 - \left(1-\frac1n\right)^n.
\end{align}
Recall that for any $z\in\mathbb C$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac zn\right)^n = e^z$. It follows that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P(S_n>0) = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1 - \left(1-\frac1n\right)^n =1-e^{-1}.
$$